# Grab specific values from json to put in data array

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to grab certain bits of data out of my JSON response to put in an array. This is my JSON response, and what I am interested in is the "counts" which is hourly, separated by either page "statement" or "logon".

```
{
   "report":{
      "type":"trended",
      "elements":[
         {
            "id":"page",
            "name":"Page"
         }
      ],
      "reportSuite":{
         "id":"retail",
         "name":"GlobPROD"
      },
      "period":"Wed.  3 Oct. 2018 - Fri.  5 Oct. 2018",
      "metrics":[
         {
            "id":"pageviews"
         }
      ],
      "segments":[
         {
            "id":"s13bb443734ab6a764639ff37",
            "name":"Information"
         }
      ],
      "data":[
         {
            "name":"Wed.  3 Oct. 2018",
            "year":2018,
            "month":10,
            "day":3,
            "hour":0,
            "breakdown":[
               {
                  "name":"CATEGORY:>Statement",
                  "url":"",
                  "counts":[
                     "242"
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"CATEGORY:>Log On",
                  "url":"...CheckId.do",
                  "counts":[
                     "237"
                  ]
               }
            ],
            "breakdownTotal":[
               "2123"
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"Wed.  3 Oct. 2018 (Hour 1)",
            "year":2018,
            "month":10,
            "day":3,
            "hour":1,
            "breakdown":[
               {
                  "name":"CATEGORY:>Statement",
                  "url":"",
                  "counts":[
                     "152"
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"CATEGORY:>Log On",
                  "url":"",
                  "counts":[
                     "135"
                  ]
               }
            ],
            "breakdownTotal":[
               "1140"
            ]
         }
```

So what I am after is firstly to be able to split out the hourly data between statement and login, and secondly build an array of the data hour by hour.

> logindata: [237, 135]
>
> statementdata: [242, 152]

I've read that I can try and grab values using something a bit like this:

```
 var t = JSON.parse('{"name": "", "skills": "", "jobtitel": "Entwickler", "res_linkedin": "GwebSearch"}');
```

But how can I create a little loop to grab all the values I specify like in my example?

Comment: From where is `137` ?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut Sorry, it was 135

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `reduce` method with `forEach` inside and build an object where each `CATEGORY` is separate property.

```js
const data = {"report":{"type":"trended","elements":[{"id":"page","name":"Page"}],"reportSuite":{"id":"retail","name":"GlobPROD"},"period":"Wed.  3 Oct. 2018 - Fri.  5 Oct. 2018","metrics":[{"id":"pageviews"}],"segments":[{"id":"s13bb443734ab6a764639ff37","name":"Information"}],"data":[{"name":"Wed.  3 Oct. 2018","year":2018,"month":10,"day":3,"hour":0,"breakdown":[{"name":"CATEGORY:>Statement","url":"","counts":["242"]},{"name":"CATEGORY:>Log On","url":"...CheckId.do","counts":["237"]}],"breakdownTotal":["2123"]},{"name":"Wed.  3 Oct. 2018 (Hour 1)","year":2018,"month":10,"day":3,"hour":1,"breakdown":[{"name":"CATEGORY:>Statement","url":"","counts":["152"]},{"name":"CATEGORY:>Log On","url":"","counts":["135"]}],"breakdownTotal":["1140"]}]}}

const result = data.report.data.reduce((r, e) => {
  e.breakdown.forEach(el => {
    let key = el.name.split(':>')[1];
    if(!r[key]) r[key] = []
    r[key].push(...el.counts)
  })
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think (if the json structure is always the same) you could do it like this:

```
for( let item in json.report.data ){
  for( let subItem in item.breakdown ){
    if( subItem.name === "CATEGORY:>Statement" ){
      //do something with subItem.counts, the statement counts
    } else if( subItem.name === "CATEGORY:>Log On" ){
      //do something with subItem.counts, the logOn counts
    }
  }
}
```